# Prevent certain lines of a script to run as root

Tags: shell-script, scripting, security, root

Suppose I am writing a shell script that requires root privileges to run, for example-

```
#!/bin/sh
ip -s -s neigh flush all
ufw enable
```

How can I prevent certain lines of code to be run as root, i.e. suppose I add a line in the above script which starts the TOR browser .

```
#!/bin/sh
ip -s -s neigh flush all
ufw enable
sh -c '"/home/back/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/home/back/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k
```

As TOR always run in non root mode, what changes should I make in the above script to allow execution of tor as non-root user and rest of the script as root user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sudo`:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip -s -s neigh flush all
ufw enable
sudo -Hu username sh -c '"/home/back/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/home/back/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k
```

- `-H`: Sets the `$HOME` environment variable to the target user's home directory
- `-u`: Runs the command as the specified target user instead of as `root`
- `username`: Argument to `-u`; specifies the target user's username

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about this.

1) Run the script as a non-root user and use `sudo` to raise privileges to the root user (prefix the commands to be ran as root with `sudo`).

or

2) Run the script as root user and use `su` to run the tor command as non-root user. `su` allows you to stipulate what user to run the command as and the `-c` option to specify what commands to run. I would also suggest putting the "tor" command in a script itself if calling it via `su`.

Comment: second method didnt work for me. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: Did you put the `tor` command line into a script before calling it with `su`?

Comment: `su` only works if he target user has a login shell that's actually a shell, which isn't always the case for system users.